# What is the name and author of this old Journey to the West comic book (Image in the post)?

Tags: story-identification, comics, journey-to-the-west

I've tried to search for this old comic book about *[Journey to The West](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_media_adaptations_of_Journey_to_the_West#Comics)* that I read when I was a kid. Below are some images of this old *Journey to the West* comic book that I found in Vietnamese. I believe this comic book must be published in some other countries too. I'm trying to find the name and author of this comic book so I can seek the origin and more detail of it.

[image: a photograph of pages 34 & 35 of the book]
[image: a photograph of pages 124 & 125 of the book]
[image: a photograph of pages of the book]
[image: a photograph of pages 104 & 105 of the book]

Comment: If it's an adaptation of the original "Journey to the West", that's a famous Chinese novel attributed to Cheng'en. There are lots of various media adaptations. Here's a link to a comic one: https://www.amazon.com/Journey-West-Classic-Volumes-Chinese/dp/7536829078

Comment: Thank JohnP, I can't tell if it's this comic book cause there is no preview image of its content at Amazon, but I gonna believe you.

Comment: @123iamking did you ever find an answer? If you're still active here, I'm willing to set a bounty to help you get an answer.

Comment: @SQB - Thanks for your kindness, but I don't need the answer anymore because I have found the chapter I need in my old warehouse, so I won't need to re-buy the chapter anymore. But the publisher didn't include any information of the original author (they just included the information of the translators, re-drawers) so I can't self-answer this question.